# How to consume response from Knox module?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, knox-amazon-s3-client

I am using the Knox S3 module, but when I eventually get the file, the resulting file is corrupt.  Am I using Knox incorrectly?

```
        var data;
        client.getFile(path, function(err, file) {
            file.on('data', function(chunk) { data += chunk; });
            file.on('end', function() {
                //Here I end up sending the response with new Buffer(data), but that produces a bad file.
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the writeStream:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file = fs.createWriteStream(path);
client.getFile(path, function(err, stream) {
    stream.on('data', function(chunk) { file.write(chunk); });
    stream.on('end', function(chunk) { file.end(); });
});
```

and make sure to take a look at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js

Comment: Just an explicit thank you for revealing Amazon's own SDK.  Not sure how I missed that!